# How to use TerminateProcess() to close a console window

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, shellexecuteex

My C++ application starts a .cmd file as a child process like this:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFOA execInfo = {0};
execInfo.cbSize = sizeof(execInfo);
execInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS | SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;
execInfo.lpVerb = "open";
execInfo.lpFile = "test.cmd";
execInfo.lpDirectory = "C:\\some\\directory";
execInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
BOOL result = ShellExecuteExA(&execInfo);
```

The script `test.cmd` runs a console-mode .NET application that runs a long time, and it looks similar to this:

```
@echo off
echo Starting a long task...
dotnet.exe runforhours.dll
```

When `ShellExecuteExA()` returns in my C++ application, the process handle in `execInfo.hProcess` is saved for later use.  The idea was to use that process handle to shut down the child process (script + exe).

But when I try to shut it down, nothing seems to happen.  The console window and the long-running .NET application both happily continue running.  This is the call to `TerminateProcess()`:

```
TerminateProcess(child_process_handle, 1);
CloseHandle(child_process_handle);
```

Should `TerminateProcess()` be expected to work in this case?  Is it perhaps because this is a console window that it isn't working?

Comment: Right now you're flying blind. Check `TerminateProcess`'s return value when you call it. If you get a return of zero, it failed and you may get more information from `GetLastError`.

Comment: Also worth noting `TerminateProcess` requests shutdown and returns. The other process will shut down later. It might be a while later.

Comment: Upvoted @RbMm, use `CreateProcess`

Comment: you create `cmd.exe`, it start `conhost.exe` - you view the `conhost.exe` window really. then `cmd.exe` start you .NET application, which use the same `conhost.exe`. then you kill initial `cmd.exe`. but this is invisible process - *nothing seems to happen*. the `conhost.exe` exit only when no more process used it, but in your case it used by your .NET application - as result it not exit and command window still visible. you possible can create job (terminate all on close), use `CreateProcess` in suspended state, assign it to job and resume.

Comment: You at best terminate cmd.exe, not the program(s) that were started by the .cmd file.  Like dotnet.exe.  It is a console program, that helps, consider GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent().